# JqCloud Implementation in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to integrate the JQCloud in angular2. I am able to access jquery in my ts file but not able to access JQ Cloud in ts.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
   //here you will have code where component content is ready.
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/dist/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.min.js";
    jQuery("head").append(s);

    jQuery('#jqcloud').jQCloud(this.data,{
    width: 500,
    height: 350
    });
```

}

Please guide me.

Comment: Maybe I've missed this lesson, but why are you dynamically adding a script tag in your `ngAfterViewInit`, and not just use the same way as you added `jQuery` to your project? As interesting as this looks, this is not at all best practice. If you do want to go at it like this, try adding the `jQuery.jqCloud` function in a `s.onload` function

Comment: You might not be able to access JQ Cloud because although you added the script the file download takes some time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   //here you will have code where component content is ready.
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "http://mistic100.github.io/jQCloud/dist/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.min.js";
    jQuery("head").append(s);

    // FILE DOWNLOAD TAKES SOME TIME HERE.
    // YOU MIGHT WANT TO SET A TIMEOUT.
    setTimeout(function(){
       jQuery('#jqcloud').jQCloud(this.data,{
          width: 500,
          height: 350
       });
    }.bind(this), 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As PierrDuc said, you should import it into your project the same way you added jQuery.

There is an NPM module called [jqcloud-npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jqcloud-npm)

```
npm install --save jqcloud-npm
```

Then in your main.ts (or where you import jquery):

```
import 'jqcloud-npm';
```

You can then check that jqcloud is available in your ts file:

```
declare var jQuery: any;
...    
console.log(jQuery().jQCloud);
```

Seems like an safer solution than trying to add a script after the view is initialized.  No race condition with downloading the script and accessing jQCloud within the setTimeout function.